# Uno-Platform: OpenGL in cross platform app

Tags: uno-platform

Does anyone know if there is a way to embed an OpenGL view in an Uno-Platform app?  I need it to work across iOS, macOS, Android and UWP.  I have a lot of C# / Xamarin code I'd like to reuse.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal implementation of OpenGL for all platforms. Some does not support it at all...

- **Android**: You may use the [`Android.Opengl` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.opengl)
- **iOS**: You may use [`GLKit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/glkit)
- **macOS**: You may use [`NSOpenGLView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsopenglview) **BUT IT IS DEPRECATED** (Apple is suggestion to use MetalKit instead)
- **Wasm**: You need to use WebGL, a subset of OpenGL.
- **Windows**: A popular way is to use GTK3
- **Linux**: A popular way is to use GTK3

Right now, the only universal API available for graphic rendering with Uno Platform is SKIA. I don't know if it suits your case, but here's a Uno sample running SKIA on multiple platforms: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/tree/master/UI/SkiaSharpTest

Comment: For UWP, someone made a fairly simple library for OpenGL ES via ANGLE: https://github.com/j4m3z0r/GLUWP